# Monitor free disk space on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics, azureportal

Is there some way how to monitor free disk space from the Azure Portal?

I know that there are all kinds of diagnostics for I/O, memory, network, CPU, .NET, SQL, ASP.NET, IIS, etc.

But is there some way to see how much free space there's on a disk attached to the VM?

All I found was this third-party solution:

http://cloudmonix.com/blog/how-to-monitor-free-disk-space-on-azure-vms/

But there should be some way how to see a basic metric like disk space without needing third-party SW, right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update 2019**

This is possible today. To monitor free disk space per drive with Azure Monitor do the following:

1. [Enable Guest Operating System OS Metrics for the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics#enable-extended-metrics-in-the-azure-portal).
2. In the **Azure Portal** select the Virtual Machine.
3. Click **Diagnostics Settings** (under Monitoring).
4. Click the **Performance counters** tab.
5. Click the **Custom** button.
6. In the textbox add the custom metric for the drive you would like. e.g. `\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space`.
7. Click **Add** and set the **Unit** to `Percent`.

Source: Azure Support.

---

To view the logs from the Azure Guest Monitor for Linux:

```bsh
// Virtual Machine free disk space
// Show the latest report of free disk space, per instance
InsightsMetrics
| where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Tags
// arg_max over TimeGenerated returns the latest record
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, Val, Tags
```

This results in the following alert query (you need `AggregatedValue` and `bin(TimeGenerated, <some time>)` in the query):

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| summarize AggregatedValue=arg_min(Val, *)  by bin(TimeGenerated, 5min), Tags
```

---

To view the same for any generic diagnostics endpoint (thanks @gabe):

After turning this on, i was able to view the free disk space with a log query:

```bsh
// Virtual Machine free disk space 
// Show the latest report of free disk space, per instance 
Perf 
 | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" or 
// the object name used in Windows records 
  ObjectName == "Logical Disk" // the object name used in Linux records 
 | where CounterName == "Free Megabytes" 
 | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by InstanceName 
// arg_max over TimeGenerated returns the latest record 
 | project TimeGenerated, InstanceName, CounterValue
```

Comment: after turning this on, i was able to view the free disk space with a log query: `// Virtual Machine free disk space
// Show the latest report of free disk space, per instance
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" or  // the object name used in Windows records
  ObjectName == "Logical Disk"          // the object name used in Linux records
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by InstanceName // arg_max over TimeGenerated returns the latest record
| project TimeGenerated, InstanceName, CounterValue`

Comment: It's very helpful indeed. Can you please tell me how to achieve it using ARM?

Comment: I'm not able to see any output from these queries. I assume you need App Insights enabled to run the one but it shouldn't be needed for @gabe's query, right?

Comment: 2021 this answer is not sufficient for linux VM, there is no "Performance counters" tab and I can't really add any metric with these steps

Comment: I don't see the option "custom"  in a scale set, correct?

Answer (score 2):

For now, it is not possible on Azure Portal.

But you could do it by using [Azure OMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview). There is a [example](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/cfuller/archive/2016/02/08/using-oms-to-visualize-server-health-based-on-free-disk-space/) how to use Azure OMS to monitor free disk.

Comment: Still not possible a year later?

Comment: Can you provide some step by step examples of how to do this? Both articles are a little unclear as how to do this per disk.

Comment: Is it still not possible 3 years later?

Comment: What about 4 years later?

Comment: What about now?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today through Azure Portal or Azure Monitor. Free disk space is a guest OS performance counter. If this is a Windows VM, you can use the Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) agent to collect performance counters to either Azure Storage table and/or EventHub and setup custom tool to monitor this data. If this is a Linux VM, there is also the equivalent Linux Diagnostic Extension.

Here are some relevant links on WAD -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-diagnostics-template?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-streaming-event-hubs

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Azure portal. In the VM resource page select the Logs blade and search "free disk". You'll get a default query which can be run to get the disk usage.
You can pin this query to dashboard or send it to workbook to check the usage frequently.

Reference - [Microsoft Techcommunity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability/i-want-see-an-alert-when-my-disk-space-less-than-5gb-in-virtual/m-p/2210373)