# Azure VM: monitor individual disk free space

Tags: azure

I'd like to monitor individual disks for an Azure VM. Guest OS metrics give me only `\LogicalDisk\%Free Space`, which is the free space for all disks combined. I can't find `\LogicalDisk(C:)\%Free Space` for example. Is there a way to monitor each disk separately?

I found this but it didn't help:
[Monitor free disk space on Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853392/monitor-free-disk-space-on-azure-vm)

Comment: It turned out I needed to manually add the metric, it isn't available by default in the interface.

Comment: perhaps post how you did that so other can benefit as well