# need assistance with Kusto query for azure vm storage details

Tags: azure, workspace, kql

I'm new with kusto and trying to write a query to return all the vm's in a resource group with total storage and available space.  Also, is there a way to query the SQL Server properties installed on a vm?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you enough information on how to capture disk space utilisation on VM's

[Monitor free disk space on Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853392/monitor-free-disk-space-on-azure-vm)

Not sure if this would surface SQL Server diagnostics information though.